# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I have to evaluate the following improper integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)} dx.$$
I used contour integration to evaluate this taking $f(z)$ as follows:
$$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z(z^2+1)}.$$

$z=0,i,-i$ are the singularities of $f(z)$. But we can see that $z=0$ is simply  a removable singularity and not a pole. While $z=i,-i$ are simple poles.

I chose the contour to be a large semicircle of radius $R$ and its diameter along the real axis from $-R$ to $R$. The only pole $z=i$ lies within the contour.

Next, I calculated the residue at $z=i$ which comes out to be equal to $$\frac{\sinh(1)i}{-2}= \frac{e-\frac{1}{e}}{-4}i.$$
Finally applying the residue theorem, we get the value of integral as:
$$I= 2πi\left(\frac{e-\frac{1}{e}}{-4}i\right)= \frac{π(e-\frac{1}{e})}{2}.$$
This result is not the same as we get using the following $f(z)$:
$$f(z)= \frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)}$$ which gives us value of the integral as $$I= π\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right).$$
Why is this the case? Why don't the two approaches give the same result? Please help.

Comment: Why did you undid my edit? I was fixing a MathJax error. Or did you really wanted $e^(iz)$?

Comment: What happens with the value of the integral along the semi-circular arc from $-R$ to $R$ in the first case when you let $R\to +\infty$?

Comment: @Gary As usual it should go to 0 as per Jordan's Lemma.

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT Could you show the details of that? Note that $\sin(z)$ grows exponentially when $\Im z \to +\infty$.

Comment: @jjagmath It happened unintentionally. I just wanted to correct my error where I had divided by $2$. I did not want $e^(iz)$.

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT It was not you who edited it and we in fact kept the edit by jjagmath.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Where does $(i+1)$ come from?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But then $z+i \to 2i$ and not $i+1$.

Comment: Whoops, yes, will delete my comments.

Comment: But it is still not clear why we’d expect the circle pat of the integral to go to $0$ as $R\to \infty.$ For example, when $z=iR,$ $f(z)\sim \frac{e^R}{R^3}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)}$ works with this curve ( almost, see below) because $|e^{iz}|\leq 1$ for $\mathrm{Im}(z)\geq 0,$ so the integral of that function along the circle **does** converge to $0$ as $R\to \infty$ there.

But $|\sin(z)|$ can be large when $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0.$

Part of the confusion might be that $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z),$ so you might think when $|\sin(z)|$ is large, so is $e^{iz}.$ But remember, $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ are both complex, for complex $z,$ and the values cancel.

If $z=a+bi,$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R,$ $b\geq0.$ Then $|e^{iz}|=e^{-b}\leq 1.$

But $$|\sin(z)|\geq\left|\frac{e^{b}-e^{-b}}{2}\right|$$

So $|\sin(z)|$ can be very large when $b$ is large, and therefore, we can’t conclude the integral of the half-circle converges to $0$ as $R\to\infty.$

---

(*) The problem with the $g(z)$ case is that $g(z)$ has a pole at $0.$ So you’ll need to alter the curve to avoid $0.$

You can avoid the pole at $0$ by integrating instead: $$g_2(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z(z^2+1)}$$ removing the pole, and then take the imaginary part of the result.

Then $|e^{iz}-1|\leq 2$ when $\textrm{Im}(z)\geq0,$ so this still works.